# How does executable names affect the offset of their address?

Tags: c, memory-management, compilation, stack, virtual-memory

I am doing a programming exercise which I am trying to understand the affects of the logic memory address offset from my stack frame base.

Assuming I have two scripts, one, lets call it 'Dumb', is creating a local variable 'j' in main and assign the value 12, open a text file, saves the address of this variable on the text file and closing the text file.
At the end I have the sleep(300) command.
Another source file, lets call it 'Dumber', in the same location is again creating a variable 'j', assign the number 16, open the text file that the previous exe created and read the address from there.
The next step is to to assign the value of 'j' from the current source file to the variable located at that address.

Here are the two source files:

```
/*DUMB*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    int i = 7;
    int j = 12;
    int k = 15;
    int *p = &j;

    FILE *fp;

    if(0 == (fp = fopen("stoopid", "w")))
    {
        printf("well, that didn\'t work!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fprintf(fp, "%p\n", p);

    if(fclose(fp))
    {
        printf("oh well.");
        return -1;
    }

sleep(300);

return 0;
```

}

```
/*DUMBER*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    int i = 8;
    int j = 16;
    int k = 32;
    int *p = &j;

    FILE *fp;

    if(0 == (fp = fopen("stoopid", "r")))
    {
        printf("well, that didn\'t work!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%p\n", &p);

    if(fclose(fp))
    {
        printf("oh well.");
        return -1;
    }

     printf("p points to: %d\n", *p);

    return 0;
}
```

The instructions are as follow:

```
1. disable ASLR.
2. compile Dumb and name it whichever you want.
3. compile Dumber and name the exe with the same name length as you named Dumb exe.
4. run Dumb exe
5. run Dumber exe
```

I understand why I get the result I get. What I don't understand is the affects of the name of the executable.

Your wisdom please

Comment: The command line arguments are on the stack.  When the program name changes size, the amount of stack used for the command line arguments changes.

Comment: Use godbolt.org to look at the generated assembly code, then you should be able to see the difference.

Comment: You have not shown the source code you used or the output you obtained. Do not expect any detailed explanation without providing details.

Comment: The "address of this variable " is not certainly in the same address space in the next program that "assign the value of 'j' from the current source file".

Comment: @EricPostpischil I added the source code of both files

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hi, Thank you. I understand that, what I don not understand is why when I change the amount of chars in the name, sometimes it will result the value I expect (16), and sometimes it will result different number such as 1 or 32767

Comment: @DeanAvivHaklai: you're invoking undefined behaviour; any result is possible and legitimate.  You could also modify the environment between invocations of the function; that too will change where things point.  There's no requirement for this to work.  It is a fairly pointless exercise, IMO.  However, if you keep things mostly the same between runs, then you can different results because of alignment changes.  Note that different compiler options would matter (variables `i` and `k` aren't used; the compiler probably omits them), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a program that provides a better way to explore this. It dumps the contents of memory from a local variable to the end of the page it is in. For a variable in a small `main` routine, that is generally to the top of the stack.

When you run this program, you will likely see that the name of the program appears in several places in memory, along with copies of the “environment variables” maintained by the command-line shell. The software that starts up new programs puts this data in memory.

Because the name of the program is on the stack, making the name shorter or longer affects how much stack space is used before the `main` routine starts executing. Since local variables that are not `static` are generally stored on the stack, the amount of stack space used affects where the local variables are located.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h> //  For getpagesize.


#define BytesPerLine    8


int main(void)
{
    //  Get the address of a variable on the stack.
    void *p = &p;

    //  Point to the end of the page that the address is in.
    void *end = (void *) (((uintptr_t) p | (getpagesize() - 1)) + 1);

    //  Round p down to the start of a group of BytesPerLine bytes.
    p = (void *) ((uintptr_t) p & -BytesPerLine);

    //  Dump memory from p to end in lines of BytesPerLine bytes.
    for (; p < end; p = (unsigned char *) p + BytesPerLine)
    {
        unsigned char *u = p;

        //  Print label.
        printf("%p: ", p);

        //  Print hexadecimal values.
        for (int i = 0; i < BytesPerLine; ++i)
            printf(" %02x", u[i]);

        //  Print characters represented, if printable.
        printf("  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < BytesPerLine; ++i)
            putchar(isprint(u[i]) ? u[i] : '.');
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```